# Is it ok not to set widget in the main page of a one page WordPress Theme?

Tags: widgets

The theme I have been developing for ThemeForest is a one page WordPress personal portfolio theme. There is no widget in the main page design which is the only showcase page of this one page theme and I didn’t set any widget in that page.

But I register a sidebar in footer for other pages like `index.php`, `page.php`, `single.php`, `archive.php`, `search.php` etc.

1. Is it ok not to set widget in the main page?
2. Is it allowed to register widget in the thememode (not as a plugin)?

Comment: So you have a widget area, but in the main demo page you didn't register any widgets? And what is "thememode"?

Comment: I have registered a widget area in footer. But I didn't active that widget in my main page as the disign doesn't support any widgetized area there.Thememode means that I registered the widget in functions.php in the theme.

Comment: If the design doesn't support a widgetized area, why did you register a widget area?

Comment: Actually I have been creating this theme for ThemeForest submission. I didn't know whether ThemeForest allows theme without widget or not.

Comment: I see. This question will be best answered in the Envato forums, but as far as I know it is entirely up to you to decide whether to have a widget area or not.

Answer (score 0):

1. Q. -> you can to set widget in main page, only need to create specify widget
2. Q. ->

   ```
   function register_my_widget(){
   register_sidebar( array(
       'name'          => esc_html__('Sidebar', 'youthemename'),
       'id'            => 'widget-1',
       'description'   => esc_html__('My first Widget', 'youthemename'),
       'before_widget' => '<div class="widget %2$s">',
       'after_widget'  => '</div>',
       'before_title'  => '<h4 class="widget-wtitle">',
       'after_title'   => '</h4>'
   ) );
   }
   add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_widget' );
   ```